# Proof that continued fractions are finite for rationals?

Tags: rational-numbers, continued-fractions

How does one prove that the continued fraction representations of rational numbers are finite?

For every $x\in\mathbb{R}$, the (simple) continued fraction representation of $x$ is:
$$
  x = [a_0; a_1, a_2, ...] = a_0 + \frac{1}{a_1 + \frac{1}{a_2 + \frac{1}{...}}}
$$
where $a_0\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $a_k\in\mathbb{N}$ for $k\geq 1$, which are themselves obtained as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
  r_0 &= x \\
  \forall k \geq 0,\quad a_k &= \lfloor r_k \rfloor \\
  \forall k \geq 0,\quad r_{k+1} &= 
\begin{cases}
1 / (r_k-a_k) & \text{if } r_k > a_k \\ 
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
and if there exists $n$ for which $r_n > r_{n+1} = 0$, then we correct $a_n\mapsto 
 a_n-1$.

Clearly if the sequence $a_k$ converges to 0, then $x$ is rational. But the converse does not seem trivial at all; why does this recursion necessarily terminate if $x = p/q$? Contraposition does not seem evident to me here either. Is there another way to think about this?

Comment: Isn't that true by definition for rationals? I don't know much about this, though.

Comment: Just do a strong induction on the denominator. It gets smaller each time

Comment: The numerators of the fractions $1/[0;a_1,a_2,...]$, $1/[0,a_2,a_3,...]$,... are a strictly decreasing sequence of natural numbers. They are the remainders in the [extended Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) applied to the numerator and denominator of the given rational number.

Comment: @RobbieVanDerzee I don't see why this would be true by definition; as far as I understand, the so-called "simple" continued fractions (with numerators all equal to 1, and with positive denominators) are just a particular "decomposition" of numbers, and it so happens that there are special properties of this decomposition for rational numbers. I might be wrong though, hence my question :)

Comment: @Sheljohn I'm probably wrong, which is why I was interested in this question. I thought since they come from a finite number over another finite number, then any repeated fraction just has to do with the divisors of each part. However, I'm excited to see what the explanations are.

Comment: @elmer I think your and Kenny Lau's comments are aligned with what I am looking for; would you be interested in writing a short answer?

Comment: @Sheljohn It is already written in the link. $a/b$ is the rational number, the $q_i$ are your $a_i$ and the $r_i$ are the numerators I was talking about. The inequality $0\leq r_{i+1}<|r_i|$ ensures that the sequence of $r_i$ cannot go on forever because the natural numbers are well ordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way for this recursion to terminate, is for the sequence of $a_k$ to converge to $0$, and this only happens when one of the $r_k$ becomes an integer.

If this is unclear to you, consider that $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\ x-\lfloor x\rfloor\in[0,1)$; therefore the only way that the $a_k$ converges to zero is if at some point $r_k = \lfloor r_k\rfloor$, i.e. $r_k$ is an integer. It is easy to see that once this happens, all further $r_k$ and $a_k$ are zero. (Note also that $a_0$ can be zero without implying convergence, which is not the case for any subsequent $a_k$.)

The main thing that changes if $x$ is a rational, is that the $r_k$ are all rational as well (subtraction with integer and reciprocal of a non-zero are both inverse of elementary operations in $\mathbb{Q}$).

> For all $k>0$, $r_k$ is either integral or a rational greater than 1.

*Proof:*

If any $r_{k\geq 0}$ is integral, then all successors are zero.

If $r_0$ is a rational less than 1, then $0 < r_0 - \lfloor r_0 \rfloor < 1$ and therefore $r_1 > 1$. Similarly if $r_k = p/q$ with $p > q > 0$ for some $k > 0$, then:
$$
  \exists n\in\mathbb{N},\quad 0 < n < \frac{p}{q} < n+1
  \quad\implies\quad
  a_k = n \quad\text{and}\quad r_{k+1} = \frac{q}{p-nq}
$$
with $p - nq < q$ (because $n$ is such that $p < (n+1)q$).

---

Incidentally, this also shows that the sequence of denominators of $r_k$ for $k > 0$ is strictly decreasing, *as long as the sequence consists of rationals*. Since these denominators are bounded below by zero, and that the previous induction applies for values greater than one, we will necessarily find a term $r_K = p/q$ for which either $q|p$ (integer case) or $p \equiv 1 \mod q$ (in which case $r_{K+1}$ is an integer).

Comment: Criticism welcome; this looks solid but a bit clumsy to me.

Answer (score 18):

it is the Euclidean Algorithm, that is all. Lots of people use "back-substitution" to finish the Extended Algorithm and find the Bezout combination, I prefer to write this as a continued fraction.

$$  \gcd( 12345, 1601 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 12345 }{ 1601 } = 7 +  \frac{ 1138 }{ 1601 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1601 }{ 1138 } = 1 +  \frac{ 463 }{ 1138 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1138 }{ 463 } = 2 +  \frac{ 212 }{ 463 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 463 }{ 212 } = 2 +  \frac{ 39 }{ 212 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 212 }{ 39 } = 5 +  \frac{ 17 }{ 39 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 39 }{ 17 } = 2 +  \frac{ 5 }{ 17 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 17 }{ 5 } = 3 +  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 5 }{ 2 } = 2 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 2 }{ 1 } = 2 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$ 
 Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 7 & & 1 & & 2 & & 2 & & 5 & & 2 & & 3 & & 2 & & 2 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 7 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 8 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 23 }{ 3 }   & &   \frac{ 54 }{ 7 }   & &   \frac{ 293 }{ 38 }   & &   \frac{ 640 }{ 83 }   & &   \frac{ 2213 }{ 287 }   & &   \frac{ 5066 }{ 657 }   & &   \frac{ 12345 }{ 1601 }  
 \end{array}
 $$ 
 $$  $$ 
 $$ 12345 \cdot 657 - 1601 \cdot 5066 = -1 $$

Comment: Wonderful formatting :) I think I get it, but now I'll have to read the proof that the Euclidean algorithm works again to convince myself... I guess it would help me to have a less "proof-by-example" approach.

Comment: Also, what is this $1/0$ there in the last line? Does this have to do with the initial values of the numerator / denominator sequences defining the convergents?

Comment: @Sheljohn actually, continued fractions are enough of an alphabet soup that your best bet is just to do a few of these by hand, perhaps beginning with smaller numbers. A mess to write out with subscripts, really not bad with actual numbers

Comment: @Sheljohn that is how the sequence of numerators and sequence of denominators start off. Those are fake fractions. See how the "digit" 7 gives you the first genuine fraction 7/1

Comment: I upvoted your answer, and I like it, but I think I will write my own answer tomorrow, following Kenny Lau's suggestion (induction on decreasing denominator sequence); it gives a very simple and direct proof. I hope this will not offend you :)

Comment: @Sheljohn all fine, but I hope you really do a few examples of this by hand.